# Postgres count total number of rows under condition, but ignore limit and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.description
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
WHERE condition
GROUP BY t1.id
LIMIT 100
```

I would like to count the total number of rows that satisfy this query past the limit *in addition* to returning the specified columns (id, name, description). The problem is that due to the GROUP BY, if I were to do a count(*), I just get a bunch of rows with 1.

So my question is: how can I count the number of rows returned by this query? And how can I do so disregarding the limit?

Also is it possible to return both the row count AND the column data in a single query? Or would I need to use two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT t1.id
  FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
  WHERE condition
  GROUP BY t1.id) sub
```

---

EDIT:

> Also is it possible to return both the row count AND the column data in a single query? Or would I need to use two queries?

Yes, using windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_of_r0ws
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id)
WHERE condition
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But wouldn't your first solution only count 100 rows? I'm looking to count ALL rows that exist disregarding the limit. For example if I had 1000 rows, but the inner query contains a limit 100, I'd still like the count to return 1000

Comment: @Andrew You could remove that limit, I do not see the point of using it at all

Comment: The limit was for pagination, but I see that your second suggestion actually accomplishes what I want. Thanks for the fast response!